# Umano Android SlidingUpPanel - error when changing language

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I am using the Umano Android SlidingUpPanel (https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), it works just the way I want it to, but when I change the language of my device, I am getting an

```
"ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: 
  com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout$SavedState"
```

exception. Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into
[this?](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/157)

Apparently it's a bug in Google Play Services.

Follow the link, it seems to be similar to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this, when I have time, I'll look into it!